# command not found for zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/carlosgrijalva/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
# agnoster, dogenpunk

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

AMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git, zsh-autosuggestions, node, yarn)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

I've manage to install zsh and use their theme, I'm trying to install [node's plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/node) but any time I type `node-docs fs` I get

> zsh: command not found: node-docs

I cam from `bash` but I uncommented the PATH. What am I missing here?

Comment: You must restart your terminal for the changes to take effect, did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I realized I had commas in my plugins!